# PHP oAuth2 with Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I am building an application using PHP and AngularJS.Trying to build rest server at the PHP end. For authentication and authorization thinking to use Oauth2. I have gone through their example url : [Oauth2 server](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/)

But how I can include it into my Application ? Also there any other way to authenticate Angular JS ?